# bash: /home/.../program: cannot execute binary file

Tags: command-line, bash

I've got a problem with simple program. When I try to run it double clicking it. Also when I try to run it by writing its path in the termilal and it says
`bash: /home/barosz/Downloads/networktablet-x86_64: cannot execute binary file`
You can find the window [here](http://s28.postimg.org/tyoakbgjh/Screenshot_from_2015_03_18_09_49_03.png)
and the program [here](https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet/blob/binaries/networktablet-x86_64?raw=true). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it mention why it can not execute? (is it executable?)

Comment: It does not say anything (no other errors in command line) but it is marked as an executable in properties.

Comment: It probably isn't compiled for your system. Where did you get it?

Comment: [here](http://rfc2822.github.io/GfxTablet/) i can't find any file to compile.. But maybe you will find..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can further debug by comparing the output of the following commands

```
$ uname -a
$ lsb_release -a
$ file /home/barosz/Downloads/networktablet-x86_64
```

quite possibly you are trying to execute a file meant for 64-bit systems on a 32-bit system.

---

In any case, I wouldn't bother about it when you can just create an executable that **is** meant for your system

```
sudo apt-get install git build-environment linux-headers
git clone git://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet.git gfxtablet && cd gfxtablet
cd driver-uinput; make
```

The resulting file is `networktablet`. You'll still have to deal with access to uinput, you can either run it as root (putting `sudo` in front) or refer to these options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939255/writing-to-dev-uinput-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: And another question - will 64-bit (AMD-64) ubuntu work on intel CPU? or the architecture doesn't allow this?

Comment: @BartoszOlszewski "AMD-64" refers to the architecture used on modern 64-bit processors made by both Intel and AMD, because it was used by AMD first (Intel had a rival 64-bit architecture called Itanium).

Comment: I'm using installed version.